# How to get the count of the number of child by using protractor

Tags: javascript, html, css, protractor

I am using Protractor to test my web application.
I try to count the number of child elements inside a parent div element, such like:

```
<div id="abc">
  <div class="a">..</div>
  <div class="b">..</div>
  <button>..</button>
</div>
```

The result should be 3, but I have no idea how to count the number with both div and button.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak to a protractor solution - but this is easy with straight javascript - and since you have tagged javascript- i thought I would share.

By using querySelectorAll and referencing the parent element and then using the direct descendant / child selector "`>`" with the wildcard selector "`*`" - you can find alll elements that are the direct children of the parent div, then use `.length` to find the number of items.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#abc > *');
const elementsLength = elements.length;

console.log(elementsLength); // gives 3
```

```html
<div id="abc">
  <div class="a">..</div>
  <div class="b">..</div>
  <button ="a">..</button>
</div>
```

EDIT - with a couple of minutes of Google searching - I found a protractor site that gave info on querying the DOm and returning a protractor test - note that I do not know Protractor at all so am using this as a suggestion for the dom query -

cite - inspred by - http://www.webdriverjs.com/find-elements-using-javascript-protractor/

```
describe('Locating element numbers using JS', function () {
    it('Identify number of children elements', function () {
        browser.get("http://angularjs.org");
        element.all(by.js(function () {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#abc > *');
            return elements;
        })).then(function (webElements) {
            const elementsLength = webElements.length;
            expect(elementsLength).not.toBe(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I've been using protractor for several years now and never knew `by.js()` was a thing. Not sure if its because I never needed it or I just never dug deep enough into webdriverjs to notice. In any case, now that I'm aware, I can think of multiple places in my current framework where this could be used to make things easier. Thanks!

Comment: Iam glad I could help - and I learned something as well.... Happy coding .. .and testing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` in css selector to get all child of any tag:

```
const child_amount = await element(by.css('div#abc > *')).count()
```